# How to Ignore nulls in case expressions using analytic Functions?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a following scenario:

This is my SQL:

```
SELECT
NAME,
CASE WHEN ECHUE LIKE 'echue' 
  THEN sum(RESTE) over (partition by NAME ,ECHUE) 
END 
    as TOT_RESTE_ECHUE, 
sum(RESTE) over (partition by NAME) as TOT_RESTE_CLIENT,
FROM TABLE
```

What i have in TABLE:

```
 Name      | ECHUE     |RESTE
-----------|-----------|---------
John       | ECHUE     | 20
John       | ECHUE     | 20
John       | null      | 20
John       | ECHUE     | 20
```

What i get:

```
 Name      | ECHUE     |RESTE    |TOT_RESTE_ECHUE | TOT_RESTE_CLIENT
-----------|-----------|---------|----------------|------------------
John       | ECHUE     | 20      |60              |80
John       | ECHUE     | 20      |60              |80
John       | null      | 20      |null            |80
John       | ECHUE     | 20      |60              |80
```

What i want:

```
 Name      | ECHUE     |RESTE    |TOT_RESTE_ECHUE | TOT_RESTE_CLIENT
-----------|-----------|---------|----------------|-------------------
John       | ECHUE     | 20      |60              |80
John       | ECHUE     | 20      |60              |80
John       | null      | 20      |60              |80
John       | ECHUE     | 20      |60              |80
```

I'm using ORACLE database version 12.
I can't use `Where ECHUE IS NOT NULL` since i need TOT_RESTE_CLIENT to be counted correclty.

Comment: probably your easiest bet is to just add `where echue is not null` to your query. Are there other values possible in the ECHUE column, other than ECHUE and null?

Comment: No there isn't, either ECHUE or NULL. i don't won't to use where echue is not null because i need to do the same thing to null in ECHUE column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( name, echue, reste ) AS
SELECT 'John', 'ECHUE', 20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'John', 'ECHUE', 20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'John', NULL,    20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'John', 'ECHUE', 20 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT t.*
       SUM( CASE WHEN echue IS NOT NULL THEN reste END )
         OVER ( PARTITION BY name ) AS tot_reste_echue
FROM   table_name t;
```

**Output**:

```
NAME ECHUE RESTE TOT_RESTE_ECHUE
---- ----- ----- ---------------
John ECHUE    20              60
John ECHUE    20              60
John          20              60
John ECHUE    20              60
```

If you do also need to `PARTITION BY` the `ECHUE` column and include `NULL` and `'ECHUE'` values together then you could do:

```
SELECT t.*
       SUM( CASE WHEN echue IS NOT NULL THEN reste END )
         OVER ( PARTITION BY name, COALESCE( echue, 'ECHUE' ) ) AS tot_reste_echue
FROM   table_name t;
```

Answer (score 0):

A query for getting the desired output is the following:

```
SELECT 
   name,
   echue,
   reste,
   (SELECT SUM(reste) FROM test t2 WHERE t2.name = t1.name) AS tot_reste_echue
FROM test t1
```

Comment: I corrected the answer accordling, hope is what you need :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way of getting the results with the null ECHUE row still present:

```
with sample_data as (select 'John' name, 'ECHUE' echue, 20 reste from dual union all
                     select 'John' name, null echue, 20 reste from dual union all
                     select 'John' name, 'ECHUE' echue, 20 reste from dual union all
                     select 'John' name, 'ECHUE' echue, 20 reste from dual)
-- end of mimicking a table called sample_data with your data in it. See SQL below:
select name,
       echue,
       reste,
       case when echue = 'ECHUE' or echue is null then
                 sum(case when echue is null then 0 else reste end) over (partition by name)
       end tot_reste_echue
from   sample_data;

NAME ECHUE      RESTE TOT_RESTE_ECHUE
---- ----- ---------- ---------------
John ECHUE         20              60
John ECHUE         20              60
John ECHUE         20              60
John               20              60
```